# How to use CSS to modify the style like a design draft

Tags: css

I encountered a problem. I made a progress bar that will run to the corresponding position according to the value of progress. But I don't quite know how to modify the dot into a pattern like the design draft of the attached drawing, so that it can be wrapped in the progress-bar.

```js
// 假設後端傳來的值是30
var progress = 10;

// 計算小圓點的位置
var dot = document.getElementById("dot");
var dotPosition = (progress / 30) * 100;
dot.style.left = dotPosition + "%";
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#progress-bar-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#progress-bar-1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progress-bar-2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progress-bar-3 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-1"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-2"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-3"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: For starters try `width: 20px; height: 10px; border-radius: 5px;` and see how that works out for you. You obviously want a 'pill' shape, so width must be > height and border radius for a pill is 1/2 of height. With `50%` you will get an elliptical odd shape.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this will cause a problem, that is, when he is at the beginning or end of the progress-bar, it will exceed the gray area~ What I want to achieve is that he is always in the gray area of ​​the progress-bar, please see Check out the changes I've made so far.

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/dyjjWgJ